# Cannot resolve the error ValueError: math domain error

Tags: python

I have the following piece of code in my function:

```
if (p < 0):
    return 0.01   
return a * math.pow(p, b) * max(e, 1)
```

It gives me the error `ValueError: math domain error` in line `return a * math.pow(p, b) * max(e, 1)`. I assumed that the source of this error is a negative value of `p` in `math.pow(p,a)`, however after adding `if` block, it still gives me an error. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show the full traceback and the values of p and b

Comment: If `b` is negative you get an error for `p=0` also. Try using `<=` in the `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the b in

```
math.pow(p,b)
```

must be an integer as supposed by the documentation:

> math.pow(x, y):
>   Return x raised to the power y. Exceptional cases follow Annex ‘F’ of the C99 standard as far as possible. In particular, pow(1.0, x) and pow(x, 0.0) always return 1.0, even when x is a zero or a NaN. If both x and y are finite, x is negative, and y is not an integer then pow(x, y) is undefined, and raises ValueError.

If this does not help try narrowing the problem down:

```
if (p < 0):
    return 0.01
tmp_pow = math.pow(p, b)
tmp_ max = max(e, 1)
return a * tmp_pow * tmp_max
```

Comment: What value does `b` exactly have?